# Must I CloseHandle() on a thread handle?

Tags: c++, windows, handle

_beginthreadex returns a handle to a thread:

```
m_hStreamStatsThread = (HANDLE) _beginthreadex( NULL, 0, StreamStatsThread, this, 0, NULL );
```

This handle may be used if you need to refer to the thread in calls like TerminateThread(..) for example.

According to [the MSDN page on _beginthreadex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdzttdcb%28v=VS.90%29.aspx), _beginthreadex won't always return a valid handle - e.g. it may also return -1L on error etc.

When a thread has completed normally, do I have to call CloseHandle on the thread handle, or can I just set its value to NULL / INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Agree with Nemanja Trifunovic.

Even after the thread exited - its handle is valid. You can for instance query its return value.

As a general rule: every Win32 handle must be closed by `CloseHandle`, unless otherwise specified.

Comment: Any Win32 *kernel* handle (i.e. anything that is of type `HANDLE`). For someone who works with WinAPI is obvious, but I've seen people trying to close windows/resource handles (`HWND`, `HICON`, ...) with `CloseHandle`. :)

Comment: Yes, you're right. The point is to close kernel handles. Those HWND, HICON, HCURSOR and etc. are user handles.

Comment: P.S. User handles - I meant - handles supported by user32.

Answer (score 4):

The code sample on the MSDN page you posted a link to includes a call to `CloseHandle()`. Setting the handle's value to NULL does not decrease the kernel object's internal ref count and is pretty much useless anyway.