# When windows releases threads?

Tags: windows, debugging, resources, windbg

Our product consumes a lot of windows resources, such as socket handles, memory, threads and so on. Usually there are 700-900 active threads, but in some cases product can rapidly create new threads and do some work, and close it. 
I came across with crash memory dump of our product. With **~*** windbg command I can see  817 active threads, but when I run *!handle* command it prints me these summary:

```
Type            Count
None            15
Event           2603
Section         13
File            705
Directory       4
Mutant          32
WindowStation   2
Semaphore       789
Key             208
Process         1
Thread          5766
Desktop         1
IoCompletion    308
Timer           276
KeyedEvent      1
TpWorkerFactory 48
```

So, actually process holds 5766 threads. So, my question, When Windows actually frees handles for process? Is it possible some kind of delay, or cashing? Can someone explain this behavior?
I don't think that we have handle leaks, but we have weird behavior in legacy part of system with rapidly creating and closing threads for small tasks. Also I would like to point, that we unlikely run more than 1000 threads simultaneously, I am pretty sure about this. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

When you say `So, actually process holds 5766 threads.`, what you really mean is that the process holds 5766 *thread handles*.

Even though a thread may no longer be running, whether that is the result of a call to [`ExitThread()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682659%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)/[`TerminateThread()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686717%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or returning from the [`ThreadProc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686736%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), any handles to that thread will remain valid. This makes it possible to do things like call [GetExitCodeThread()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683190%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on the handle of a thread that has finished its work.

Unfortunately, that means that you have to [remember to call `CloseHandle()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959473/must-i-closehandle-on-a-thread-handle) instead of just letting it leak. The MSDN example on [Creating Threads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682516%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) covers this to some extent.

Another thing that I will note is that somewhere not too far above 1000 running threads, you are likely to [exhaust the amount of virtual address space available](https://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/07/29/444912.aspx?Redirected=true) to a 32bit process since each thread by default reserves 1MB of address space for its stack.

Comment: Actually we use boost::thread::join(), to wait while thread stops. I have to check boost thread library about calling CloseHandle().
I am aware about default stack size, we override this value to 256k for our product. Thank you nevertheless.